# Inline notation of TYPO3 Fluid view helper `f:for`

Tags: fluid, view-helpers

I would like to fill an attribute value in a TYPO3 Fluid template with a loop (`f:for`) by using its inline notation:

```
<div class="one two three">[...]</div>
```

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the meanwhile I found a solution for my problem. To print all items of an array you could do something like `{x -> f:for(each: {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three'}, as: 'x')}`. But this will result in: `onetwothree`. To fix that the view helper `f:if` helps:

```
<div class="{f:if(condition: i.isLast, then: '{x}', else: '{x} ') 
    -> f:for(each: {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2: 'three'}, as: 'x', iteration: 'i')}">
    [...]
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tweak the solution of @witrin a litte more and write ind completely inline:

```
{f:if(condition: i.isLast, then: '{x}', else: '{x} ') -> f:for(each: '{item.thing}', as: 'x', iteration: 'i')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find following inline notations,
It helps you lot.

Inline Notation for for loop

```
Original -> `<f:for each="{data.title}" as="title"> {title} </f:for>`
```

Inline Notation ->  {title -> f:for(each: '{data.title}', as: 'title')}

Inline Notation for date

```
Date :-> `<f:format.date cldrFormat="MMMM y" forceLocale="{true}" localeFormatType="date">1-{calendar.month}-{calendar.year} 00:00:00</f:format.date>`

Inline Notation :-> {f:format.date(date:'1-{calendar.month}-{calendar.year} 00:00:00',cldrFormat:'MMMM y',localeFormatType: 'date', forceLocale: true)}
```

so on...

Comment: but I added more specifically with examples, btw great work @witrin

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for some 'advanced' array handeling in fluid?
have a look at https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master.html.

Comment: Nope, see my answer. By the way you should not answer with a question, use the comment function instead.